# Uniqueidentifier is incompatible with numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to parse the header information from a SQL BAK file into a table however I am getting the following error.

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with numeric
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

This is the script that I wrote but I do not understand why I am getting this error.

DECLARE @HeaderInfo2 Table

```
(LogicalName  nvarchar(128),
PhysicalName  nvarchar(128),
Type          nvarchar(128),
FileGroupName nvarchar(128),
Size          numeric(25,0), 
MaxSize       numeric(25,0),
FileId        int,
CreateLSN     int,
DropLSN       int,
UniqueId      uniqueidentifier ,  
ReadOnlyLSN   int,
ReadWriteLSN  int,
BackupSizeInBytes  numeric(25,0),
SourceBlockSize    numeric(25,0),
FileGroupId    int,
LogGroupGUID   numeric(25,0),
DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0),
DifferentialBaseGUID numeric(25,0),
IsReadOnly int,
IsPresent  int,
TDEThumbprint int
)
```

INSERT INTO @HeaderInfo2 EXEC('RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = N''I:\DBTemp\database.bak''
WITH NOUNLOAD')

Comment: Triple-check the source columns - order and data types.  One suspect is the column called `DifferentialBaseGUID` that is numeric - is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what the datatypes should be.  Is there a way to determine what the datatypes should be based on the output from the following query?  RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = N'I:\DBTemp\database.bak'
WITH NOUNLOAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datatypes are incorrect. The proper datatypes can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
Column name         Data type
LogicalName         nvarchar(128)
PhysicalName        nvarchar(260)
Type                char(1)
FileGroupName       nvarchar(128)
Size                numeric(20,0)
MaxSize             numeric(20,0)
FileID              bigint
CreateLSN           numeric(25,0)
DropLSN             numeric(25,0)NULL
UniqueID            uniqueidentifier
ReadOnlyLSN         numeric(25,0) NULL
ReadWriteLSN        numeric(25,0)NULL
BackupSizeInBytes   bigint
SourceBlockSize     int
FileGroupID         int
LogGroupGUID        uniqueidentifier NULL
DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0)NULL
DifferentialBaseGUID    uniqueidentifier
IsReadOnly          bit
IsPresent           bit
TDEThumbprint       varbinary(32)
```